# How many journals can one follow at the same time?

Tags: journals

I have been following 7 journals at the same time for may be about 10 years now. 4 of them are relatively unpopular and publish may be about 50 papers per year, so they are easy to follow, 1 has 100+ papers so it sometimes requires an effort to read about everything they publish but the other 2 are very popular and publish biweekly full issues with dozens of papers, so it is painful to follow them and I need to look at their webpages to see what is new almost every day. However, I'm interested in a field where I always need to look for papers outside of it and have to browse many journals irregularly to find possibly interesting information. That means I browse through dozens of journals irregularly and have to look through literally thousands of papers. And, oh God, it takes its toll. But the REAL problem is that my requirements only get broader with time, so I now can't just keep on. I think there are really too many journals and too many papers in them to browse through and I can't even manage to read through all the titles of all the papers that could potentially interest me, let alone read the abstracts.

This is why I would like to try to find someone who has similar problems and ask him/her how does s/he manage to solve them, e.g. what does it take to browse the maximum number of journals possible as far as search optimization, number of journals covered and time are concerned? Is it possible to cover a wide field and follow everything it happens in it so you could be aware of the new papers published in dozens of journals or is this simply impossible? I want to know how far can I get and how much time would the effort consume, so, if you could share with me your experience I would be very thankful.

Thank you very much!

Comment: People still follow journals? — _Is it possible to cover a wide field to follow everything it happens...._ — No.  It's not possible.

Comment: Then, what are the options @JeffE?

Comment: Realize that **nobody** knows the entire field, and that's okay, because  you don't **need** to know the entire field to make significant research contributions.  Figure out the small subset of the literature that you actually _use_ and _care about_ the most, and only follow that.  Google for key words/phrases/authors and chase references/citations when you need something outside that sphere.

Comment: I give **the maximum** I could squeeze out of myself at the cost of virtually every minute free time and even sleep-time I could get out of myself but still it is **not enough** @JeffE! I can't cover even a fraction of all the literature on all questions that interest me let alone find **all** the relevant literature in the fields I want to know about. The end result is that I must submit to the fact that I have huge gaps in my knowledge and I can't possibly fill it. But then how could I be sure I know **everything** there is out there to know about what interests me if I can't even make a

Comment: descent literature check!

Comment: @JeffE's point is exactly that you *can't* know everything that is out there, and you should accept that. You should learn to optimize how much time you spend getting updated on the recent literature, but not to the point that it jeopardizes your research, learning or quality of life. If something is really important to the point that it significantly impacts your research, you *will* hear about it whether you follow journals and keywords or not.

Comment: I tend to agree with you @glauc but the problem is I want to know can I cut the costs in both the time I spend searching for literature online and the time between the article going online and me actually learning about it. Can it be done in some way?

Comment: _how could I be sure I know everything there is out there_ — You can't.  It's not possible.  Stop killing yourself trying.

Answer (score 4):

Use a content manager and subscribe to the journals' RSS feeds.

I currently follow ~30 journals and a few blogs (this number changes dynamically as I remove some journals and include others) using [feedly](https://feedly.com), which is a RSS reader that is very user-friendly and has apps for both Android and iOS. The software automatically fetches new content from the journals' latest issues and makes them available to me in real time. My daily feed is usually comprised of ~50 new papers every day. I devote 15-30 minutes of every morning to going through it--except on some weekdays when journals like Nature and Science release an entire issue. Going through the feed includes reading all titles, identifying potentially relevant papers, reading their abstract and saving them to my [Mendeley](https://www.mendeley.com) library. Some people keep track of new papers through Mendeley alone, though I prefer feedly.

Comment: I do it similarly, just that instead of using RSS, I rely on email alerts. Those get filtered into a separate folder in my email account, and get checked on a daily basis (usually), for interesting titles. @glauc, is there an advantage of RSS above email alerts?

Comment: @Mark, I think there is. Feedly and other RSS readers keep the feed well organized in folders/saved items/etc. Second, your journal content will always go to the same place/app. You can do that with e-mails, but it requires some filter engineering that I do not see advantages over using something that has been designed just for that.

Comment: I am not sure if these reasons are persuasive, but, as a data point, my ability to track the recent literature increased significantly when I started using content managers (particularly feedly + Mendeley).

Comment: @glauc what about possible interesting papers in other journals under relevant keywords? Can this app search entire search engine's database for new papers in any journal under certain keywords combinations or it does only give you the papers in the journals you specify? I have huge problem with tracking down articles because of too broad searches with too many results, so I can't pick up those journals that are most likely to publish new papers in what I'm interested in. Can I make the app show me statistics of where relevant papers appear the most and thus recommend me journals to follow?

Comment: No, I don't think so, though I have never tried. I use feedly specifically to subscribe to journals, not to specific keywords. Mendeley and ScienceDirect feeds are good in fetching papers based on your library and keywords, and so is Google Scholar with email alerts, though I don't like having my email polluted with publication alerts that I most likely have already seen on feedly. Nonetheless, there are only so many journals where papers in my field are generally published, and I tend to subscribe to most of them. It's unlikely that you will be able to track down absolutely everything.

Comment: I don't really know if there is a tool that will provide the statistics you want, but that's a good idea for a simple Python project, given that there are Python libraries that fetch data from Google Scholar. But just like anything else, don't over-optimize. It's fairly unlikely that you will miss something relevant if you follow the ~30-50 journals most relevant to your field. Even if you do, there is a very good chance that it will show up in your next literture search.

Comment: Actually, my field **is** the problem. I am interested in something that can be described as theoretical biology but the problem is that when you put theoretical and biology in the search engine the numbers that pop up are in the hundreds of thousands. There is no human brain that can handle that! So, what I do is to put in more keywords until searches got shorter. Than I look through the papers that got in and try to find out what journals have the most of them. Finally, I try to identify the places where relevant research is most likely to appear and subscribe to them.But it has its problems

Comment: When you subscribe to too many journals your e-mail is spammed with alerts and TOCs. When you narrow the search you end up losing relevant information. The only way to optimize is through painstaking trial and error and it costs a lot of time to finally get to the "perfect" list of keywords for the perfect list of journals. Do that for many journals in many fields associated to "theoretical" and "biology" and you will end up with a list of hundreds of keywords combinations for hundreds of journals but it will cost you days and even weeks for each such combination. I want to cut the timetable!

Comment: The way I do searches now is simply too slow and time-consuming to be effective. Each time I got a new idea I have to spend literally hundreds of hours to identify a literature list relevant for it and then may be thousands of hours to actually read the thing. This is why my research efforts are incredibly slow and painstaking. I spend around 20-30 hours per week on it or about 100 hours per month and I hardly get into 2-3 fields per year. If I want to finish my research and find relevant literature quickly I need to think of a superior method to browse through huge libraries containing

Comment: hundreds of thousands of articles in thousands of journals for a few hours or so. But is it possible?

Comment: @YordanYordanov The issue is that you think your field is theoretical biology. Nobody has that as their field, as it is way too broad. Until you figure out what your subfield really is, you will have no chance of getting any handle on the relevant literature.

Comment: This is my biggest problem I can't define my own field-it has to do with theory and it has to do with biology, but it also has to do with mathematical modeling, organic chemistry, thermodynamics, philosophy of science and with almost all biomedical fields because they publish papers relevant to theories in biology. Do you know how many journals are those? How do you think one can manage to keep relevant with so many titles?

Answer (score 1):

Closely linked to the former comment and more an addon: If you register for email alerts, you can most often decide how often do you want to be informed (every article that goes OnlineFirst, just a weekly or monthly email alert or only the final journal issue).

For my work, I differentiate between journals that are really close to my field of study and I should know immediately about any study that is published (and these are the journals in which I want to publish my work), journals that are important (often more general-interest journals), but cover such a wide range of topics that many published articles are not directly relevant to me, and thus, I just get a monthly email alert. Finally there are journals that are on the margin of my research interests (or situated in other disciplines), but I like to keep track of them. For these, I get only the TOC of each published issue.

With this strategy, I can also reduce the amount of time that I devote to skim through the new email alerts. I can't really tell you the exact number of journals that are in each category, but my feeling is that the number is from the first to the last category decreasing.

I hope this helps you?!